# Proof that the non simply normal numbers in base 2 are uncountable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, normal-number

Does anyone know of a proof that the binary non-normals are uncountable in $[0,1]$ if that's even true? I am specifically referring to non simply normals, i.e numbers in which the asymptotic density of the digits $1$ and $0$ is not $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: How about the numbers with no two consecutive ones?

Comment: How about the binary sequence obtained by taking the word $0x0x0x0x\dots$ and replacing each $x$ by either $11$ or $111$?